# VirtualBox: mount a shared folder automatically in Gentoo

Tags: virtualbox, gentoo, linux-kernel, vagrant

I'm currently writing a template (in veewee) to build a vagrant box running Funtoo x86_64.
Currently, my box fails the last step for `vagrant basebox validate`, in which a shared folder has to be mounted automatically in the guest system.

What are the prerequisites for automounting of shared folders? I searched for it in the documentation for Gentoo and for VirtualBox, had a look at templates for Ubunto boxes - but still don't know how to replicate the automounting behavior of the default Ubuntu box.

I'm using genkernel with the gentoo-sources. The virtualbox-guest-additions are installed and the virtualbox daemon is started.

I'd love an answer containing these requirements (with some of my best guesses):

- Kernel config (NFS v3/4, automounter, ...?)
- Userspace programs (do I need additional packages? which daemons in which runlevel?)
- Directories and permissions (do I need a `/media` dir belonging to some user, do certain users like `vagrant` and `root` need a membership in the `vboxguest` group or a `vboxsf` group - which does not exist yet?)

but any kind of help would be great - even a single link or a hunch...

**UPDATE:** What I did so far...
I *can* mount shared folders manually, what I'm interested in is automatic mounting.

The VirtualBox website mentions a group `vboxsf` that should be created on installation of the additions - I don't see that group in `/etc/group`, I have `vboxguest`, though.

It also says that shared folders are mounted under `/media` with a prefix of `sf_` ([controllable](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders) by `/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountDir` and `/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountPrefix`). I don't have a `/media` directory either - and both properties were not set on my VM.

I created both the directory and the group and set the properties to their default values, but I'm still out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state in the last paragraph is sufficient - add `/media`, add the group `vboxsf` and **reboot** (which I didn't when I tried this before).